# Are Tumblr themes updatable by author once used on a live site

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I’ve used a Tumblr theme on a site which has been live for about 18 months and has a continuous scroll, but the other day I visited the site and the continuous scroll is no longer there. There is now a page by page pagination. I checked if this was a browser compatibility fall back thing—it wasn't.

Do updates to Tumblr themes update live sites once they've been published?

Any other thoughts why this might be?

I am the only one with access to the site so it’s not like any one changed it on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably Tumblr can update them, eg to make changes to allow them to work with newer browsers.

I don't know about Tumblr specifically, but Blogger certainly do make updates to the templates of live blogs, and I'd expect other tools to do similar.

Comment: Thanks, just a note though i dont think this is a tumblr theme, its a theme written by a 3rd party as a tumblr theme, rather than by the tumblr company (yahoo) them selves ..

Comment: That doesn't matter:  Tumblr still need the theme to work within their software, so may need to modify it as they make changes.